# what happend if gdb frams/bt show "??" but no readalbe function name?

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I encountered a coredump,use gdb xxx core.1234,then "bt",got those message:" 0x6f636d6f in ?? ()",in which the function name is not readable.I want to learn:
1. in what situations does the gdb bt show "??" as function name?
2. how to avoid these "??" and get the readable function name?

Answer (score 2):

The address 0x6f636d6f is almost certainly invalid (i.e, lies outside your process's memory space), and is probably the result of stack corruption -- it corresponds to the ASCII characters `ocmo`.

Comment: duskwuff,you mean :if it corresponds ot the ascc string,it can not be an valid address of the function?tks

Comment: It's not a given, but it's a very good guess. Most systems won't load code in that address range.

Comment: If the OP is using a little-endian machine, as is likely, then it actually corresponds to `omco`.

Answer (score 0):

1 case : stack is corrupt.
2 case : code compiles with optimisations (not sure about it).
3 case : you start gdb wrong (example gdb ./app --core core_name).

Comment: i'm not sure, but stripped binary may cause symbol name stripping.

Comment: in what situcations does stack get corrupted?

Comment: gnu strip discards all symbols from object files objfile. The list of object files may include archives. At least one object file must be given.

strip modifies the files named in its argument, rather than writing modified copies under different names. 

http://sources.redhat.com/binutils/docs/binutils/strip.html

Stack will be corrupted if code corrupts memory.